# D3js Typescript force layout link event

Tags: d3.js, typescript, force-layout

Hello I work on a D3JS project with d3.d.ts library and I have this piece of code

```
 this.force
        .nodes(this.graph.nodes)
        .links(this.graph.edges)
        .on("tick", () => this.tick())
        .start();
    this.links = this.svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(this.graph.edges)
        .enter().append("line")
        .on("click", (e: NVEdge) => { this.edge = e ; console.log("toto") })
        .on("dblclick",(e:NVEdge) => { this.edgemodalstate = true })
        .attr("class", "link");
    this.nodes = this.svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(this.graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("id", (n: NVNode) => { return n.id })
        .style('fill', (n: NVNode) => { return n.branch.color })
        .style('stroke', (n: NVNode) => { return n.branch.color })
        .on("mousedown", (n: NVNode) => { this.mousedown(n) })
        .call(this.force.drag)
        .on("mouseup", (n: NVNode) => { this.mouseupNode(n) })
        .on("dblclick", (n: NVNode) => { this.nodemodalstate = true });
    this.nodes.append("title").text((n: NVNode) => { return n.name; });
```

and the event on link does'nt seems to work

```
.on("click", (e: NVEdge) => { console.log("toto") })
```

If somebody have an idea how to solve this problem i'll be glad to hear it :D

Here all the code https://github.com/NodeVision/NodeVision/tree/dev

Comment: please consider providing a working sample